# Django 1.10 pass form object into template

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to pass my custom form into a template file.

**Template**:

```
{{ form }} #  prints nothing
```

**Views**:

```
class EntertainerDisplay(FormView):
    form_class = EntertainerCheckboxForm
    template_name = 'entertaining/custom_form.html'
```

**Form**:

```
class EntertainerCheckboxForm(forms.Form):    
    class Meta:
        model = Entertainer
        fields = ['first_name',
                  'second_name',
                  'last_name'
                 ]
```

No matter what I do, `form` variable is never in `View` context, and therefore not sent into a `template file`. How can I pass form and its fields into `form` variable in a `template file`?

Comment: `viwes.py` defines `form_class` but the template calls `{{ form }}`, instead of `{{ form_class }}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in `EntertainerCheckboxForm` definition. It should be a subclass of `forms.ModelForm`, not `forms.Form`.

Since you've defined `EntertainerCheckboxForm` as subclass for `forms.Form` and haven't added any form field manually, it doesn't render any form field because there is no field to render.

The correct definition should be as follows:

```
class EntertainerCheckboxForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Entertainer
        fields = ['first_name', 'second_name', 'last_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

In **views.py**:

from myappname.forms import EntertainerCheckboxForm

```
def my_form_view
    myform = EntertainerCheckboxForm()
    return render(request,'path/to/your/template', {'myform': myform})
```

In **template.html**:

```
{{myform}}
```